# Flush even ob flush not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, google-chrome

I am trying to insert rows into MySQL db using a for loop in php. What I want is to echo the particular row name that is being inserted while it is being done. I tried the flush method, but it didnt work, not even ob_flush.

I have then searched solutions here and found a few, tried everything but I still get the output all at once when the entire script is finished...

My code looks like this (I added some of the lines I found on the web could solve the issue, but still no luck and in the code below I deleted the mysql stuff, because that works fine, the data is written to db):

```
<?php
 header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
 ob_implicit_flush(true);
 ob_end_flush();
 $con=mysqli_connect("...");
?>

<html>
<body>

<?php
for($d=1;$d<=5;$d++){
 echo "$d";
 echo str_repeat(' ', 4096);
 ob_flush();
 flush();  
 $query = "...";
 mysqli_query($con,$query);
}

</body>
</html>
```

In this case of course the script would run instaneously, but in the real scenario it actually takes a bit of time for each loop to do the stuff inside it, so I get the final echo after everything is finished after about 10s. And I would like to echo it after each for loop iteration, i.e. approximately every 2s

Comment: Browser-based output is not the same as command line or console-based output. You could consider asynchronous requests to populate query execution results as they are happening.

Comment: console also shows nothing and in that case, how would I flush this in the browser, in other words I just want the user to see what is happening and how far the script is

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for me. HOWEVER, it didn't *seem* to work at first, because of the long string of spaces that was pushing the staggered responses off to the right, where I couldn't see the responses.

See `THIS LINE HERE` below:

```
<?php 

$db_host = '...';
$db_user = '...';
$db_pass = '...';
$db_name = '...';

$con = new mysqli(
    $db_host,
    $db_user,
    $db_pass,
    $db_name
);

if ($con->connect_error) {
    echo "$con->connect_error";
    exit;
}

for ($d = 1; $d <= 5; $d++){
    echo $d;
    echo str_repeat(' ', 4096);
    echo PHP_EOL; // <<< THIS LINE HERE

    ob_flush();
    flush();

    $query = "SELECT SLEEP(5)";

    mysqli_query($con, $query);
}
```

This (simpler test) also worked:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    echo "$i is run." . PHP_EOL;

    ob_flush();
    flush();

    sleep(10);
}
```

So, create a stand-alone page, paste the above into it and fill in the database details. Then run it and see if you get the output. If you do, then you have some (similar or otherwise) problem with the code you didn't include. If not, it's possible the configuration of your server is somehow preventing it from working.

First, though, try to get a simpler version to work, then go from there. This is also a decent primer:

http://www.sitepoint.com/php-streaming-output-buffering-explained/